# Exclude certain URL patterns from Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4 in my Struts app and want all the URLs to go through Spring Security except the URLs starting with `/rest`. How can I get this to work as I understand that regex patterns are not allowed to be used in web.xml.

Hence, `<url-pattern>^(?!\/rest).*$</url-pattern>` does not work.

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>^(?!\/rest).*$</url-pattern>              <!-- Doesn't work -->
</filter-mapping>
```

**security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired" request-matcher="regex">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/(css|fonts|help|images|layouts|scripts).*$" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/login.*$" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/logout.*$" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/accessDenied.cprms$" access="permitAll"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="^.*.jsp$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/errors\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole','changePasswordRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/control\/.*$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/control\/jobStatus.cprms$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/sysad\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/userad\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','adminRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/myprofile\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole','changePasswordRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/carpark\/carParkDetails.cprms$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/carpark\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/product\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/splevt\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/alert\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/location\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','supportRole','nolocation')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/competitor\/details\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/competitor\/product\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/consolidator\/interface\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','adminRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/consolidator\/details\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/config\/consolidator\/product\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/monitor\/config\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/monitor\/configure\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/monitor\/operation\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('superRole','systemRole','supportRole','adminRole','businessRole','operationalRole')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/recommendedSettings.cprms$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/.*errors.cprms$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/upload\/uploadExtract\/.*$" access="hasAnyAuthority('uploadExtractRole')"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="^\/.*$" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <security:form-login
                login-page="/loginRedirector.jsp"
                login-processing-url="/login"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                default-target-url="/welcome.jsp"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                username-parameter="j_username"
                password-parameter="j_password"
        />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/loginRedirector.jsp" />

        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/loginRedirector.jsp">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="globalDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT user_id AS `username`, PASSWORD AS `password`, IF(user_locked = 'N', 1, 0) AS `enabled` FROM `user` WHERE user_id = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.user_id AS `username`, r.NAME AS `role` FROM `user` u INNER JOIN user_role ur ON ur.user_fk = u.user_pk INNER JOIN role AS r ON ur.role_fk = r.role_pk WHERE u.user_id = ?"
            />
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ssoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.ideas.carparkpro.core.service.impl.LoginFailureHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/>
    <beans:bean id="ssoAuthenticationProvider" class="com.ideas.carparkpro.core.service.impl.SSOAuthenticationProvider" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: It looks like you're explicitly setting all of your security settings for each of your controllers in `security.xml`, in that case do you need to have anything for `/rest`? I would assume if there is no setting defined it won't restrict it.

Comment: @dbaltor It doesn't seem to work somehow. However, I have fixed it by while listing all the URLs one by one that needs to be tracked by spring security in web.xml.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm glad you found out a solution in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it but I think this could work for you: [DelegatingFilterProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/security-filter-chain.html#security-filter-chain).

To use it, you need to add the snippet below to your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and then configure the `filterChainProxy` bean to whitelist the `/rest` URL whilst applying all filters you need to the general case. Here is an example:

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/rest/**" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,
        basicAuthenticationFilter,
        formLoginFilter,
        securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The order above is important. The more restrict URLs must come first.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on the question, you *may* not need to define the controller to not have any security settings. But if you do, there are already other controllers in your `security.xml` that do something similar:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="^\/rest/*$" access="permitAll"/>
```

Comment: I have a different way to authenticate the URLs starting with `/rest`, so not sure if this would work.